# cart call to action color on mobile

Tags: e-commerce, color, shopping-cart

We are designing an e-shop for a bakery.
What do you think about the yellow call to action button to complete the order?

The other option is a black button.

Which one do you think would create more convertions?

The selected color will be used also in the Desktop version.

[image: two variations]

Comment: What are your palette of colors for the rest of the page/site? Is it grayscale like the mock shows or are there going to be clashing colors around this button?

Comment: The whole website is on B&W. The only color we added is the yellow.

Comment: Only performing an A/B test will lead you to the right option. Online articles or opinions never work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides anything, take a look to the *["Which Color Converts the Best?"](http://conversionxl.com/which-color-converts-the-best/)* article and then [How To Design Call to Action Buttons That Convert](http://unbounce.com/conversion-rate-optimization/design-call-to-action-buttons/). Just in case you don't want to read them, the absolute answer is "could be anything". In your specific case, yellow is quite possibly the best choice because of contrasting and disruption of the palette, but you'll need to test if yellow or another color other than black or white are the best choice! For example, I think a mid way from your shade of yellow to pure orange would work wonders on a bakery shop.

Then again: **test, test, test!** Luckily, it's really easy on button colors

Comment: +1, while my answer did say "I suggest using the yellow" I was choosing between the 2 options. I would recommend looking into other colors as Devin states because the black on bright yellow can be a little straining on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only color added would be to the call to action I would certainly suggest using the yellow button. why?

> **Color is very important when trying to create emphasis.** I wrote a post on my blog that recommended you let your hyperlinks shine. Well, your call-to-action buttons should shine even brighter. After all, if you’re using them correctly, these buttons will take people to the most important stuff.

[Good Call-To-Action Buttons](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/good-call-to-action-buttons/)

> **USE HIGHLY CONTRASTING COLORS**
>   Deciding what colors to use for call to action buttons is very important. Use colors in your call to action buttons that have a high contrast relative to surrounding elements and the background because it is critical to ensure that the user notices your call to action.

[Call to Action Buttons: Examples and Best Practices](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/call-to-action-buttons-examples-and-best-practices/)

These are just the first two sites I found out of the many that will recommend making your calls to action stand out against the rest of your page. Users are looking for a sense of direction and what to do next, you don't want them to get lost. Guide thier attention buy making thier path stand out, especially if it is the action you **want** them to perform like completing the order.